# How do I determine if a page is a MODAL

Tags: javascript

Is there any way in JavaScript I can see if the page I am loading is a modal?

I know I can see if it's in iframe by doing something like this:

```
var isInIFrame = window.location != window.parent.location ? true : false;
```

But I wanted to know if there was code to see if it was a modal window.

Comment: What is a "modal page" supposed to be?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

Comment: something like this..

  window.showModalDialog("showModalDialog_target.htm", "", 
      sFeatures)

Answer (score 2):

You can check for `window.dialogArguments`.

```
if (window.dialogArguments) {
  // modal window
}
```

Edit: That also applies to showModelessDialog, but if you don't use that function, then this works.